# why do we need complementary slackness in KKT conditions?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am quite confused about complementary slackness in KKT Conditions.

here are my series of questions

1. why do we need complementary slackness?
2. does strong duality implies complementary slackness? if yes then how?
3. does complementary slackness imply strong duality?

Comment: Being precise in your question is already half the answer: what do you mean with 'strong duality' in question 2? And what does question 4 mean?

Comment: by strong duality, I mean primal and dual optimal values are the same. sorry about question 4 it's redundant. I am editing the question accordingly

Comment: That does not make sense. You seem to talk about properties of the primal and dual (namely their optimal values are the same), whereas complementary slackness is about points in primal and dual space.

Comment: The complementary slackness arises as a consequence of writing the Lagrangian in reduced form, if instead you include explicitly all the non-negativity constraints  and their respective multipliers then you'll see this.

Comment: Chapter 5 of Boyd and Vandenberghe explains the KKT conditions pretty clearly. https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/